# How to list via HTTP directory which name starts from dot?

Tags: .htaccess, http, directory

I have some third party app, which needs presence on the remote server directory called ".a3s". In this directory there are some config files which should be remotely available.
Problem is i can't access to this directory when i will put it on remote server.
When i try to enter to it using Firefox via HTTP:

```
some_page.com/.a3s/readme.txt
```

i recieve:

```
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this document.
```

I tried to edit .htaccess in parent directory however i've failed.

My .htaccess (all below is standard WordPress addition):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This isn't my server. Provider is home.pl. Only way i can manipulate files is via ftp or special console in browser (but there are no specific options to set).

Permission of ".a3s" is 755 and files in it 644.
How to solve such situation? Maybe there is some way to fool HTTP and redirect question about ".a3s" to "_a3s"?

---

This is workaround of this problem in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^repo_cfog/.a3s/(.*) repo_cfog/_a3s/$1 [L]
```

Comment: "How to solve such situation?" By providing more information. Currently all you have said is that your permission is denied. We cannot magically fix that, there is a reason for that. That reason is on your systems where we do not have any access to. I suggest you post the `.htaccess` style files and the file permissions.

Comment: Please also post information about the web server. Is it yours or a shared host? Many apache configurations include a rule in the main .conf file to forbid any files beginning with `.`.  It's often implemented with a `<FilesMatch>` directive inside `apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf`.

Comment: What are the file permissions on those files?

Comment: I've added additional info in my first post.

Comment: Do the yprovide you server/access/error logs?

Comment: I have no logs and i have no ability to access httpd.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason of my problem was my provider.
He just blocked on the level of httpd access to all directories with dot on the begining.
Solution is: call to your provider and tell him that you want access. If he will answer "no", call once again and be more assertive, and so one.